# body {position: relative;}

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to position my document with CSS, and I was wondering what the consensus is on setting the body element's position property to relative to establish the initial containing block. Is this considered bad practice? I've read that it isn't necessary, and that, say, if the body element's first child is absolutely positioned, it's containing block defaults to the HTML element, which is equivalent to the viewport. I'm confused because I can't seem to get the positioning to work without body {position: relative;}.

Here is the HTML and CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="div1">

        <p id="p1">
            content
        </p>

    </div>

    <div id="div2">

        <p id="p2">
            content
        </p>

    </div>

</body>
</html>

body{
    position: relative;
}

#div1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    width:auto;
    margin: auto;
}

#p1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    background-color: aqua;
}

#div2 {
    position:absolute;
    top: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}

#p2 {
    position: absolute;
}
```

I threw this example together so I can start messing with the different values for `position`, `margin`, and `width`. This is a lot different than what I originally posted. I was hoping to understand how to set the initial context for all of the other positioned elements in the document so that I can eventually understand how the browser calculates the auto value. I started to get confused by trying to automatically set widths and center elements on the page.

Comment: What specific issues are you having if you don't set position relative on the body?

Comment: Thanks @Chaim. When I don't use it, none of the positioning works, as if it's all normal flow, which is what I expected. I'm just wondering if I shouldn't do it this way, as I've read that it's unnecessary. Sorry I can't point back to where. I went down a bit of a rabbit hole. If this is okay to do and isn't considered a no-no, specifically on the body element, that would be perfect.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary. But post what you have so far with a specific question/problem, otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: Sorry about that, still new to this.

Comment: Please update your question itself to include your code that you have tried so far -- we can't work out what the problem is without it. Having said that, I've never personally encountered a situation where you need to define a position on the `<body>` element.

Comment: I'm not surprised you're confused. Sadly, there's a lot of misinformation about the Initial Containing Block. Its not the viewport, it's never the body element, nor even the html element. It doesn't map to any element and can't be made so. It's *always* a virtual box that *contains* the root element (i.e. for valid HTML, it's the container of  the `<html>` element). It has the height and width of the viewport, but unlike the viewport, Its top left corner (assuming left-to-right layout) is fixed to the origin (0, 0) on the canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes and no.

Yes not because it is the `body` tag, but because it is the parent of your `position:absolute` tag in this case. The `position:absolute` is always refer to its parent, which need to be set as `position:relative`.

No in general you don't need to set position for the `body` tag. If your `#div` has a parent container like `<div class = "container">`, the `.container` would need to be set as `position:absolute`.

Comment: Thanks, Cheung! A couple of follow-up questions, if you don't mind. I should have clarified that this question, for me, mostly concerns the containing blocks for the first element in the document that has a position value other than static. What then becomes that element's containing block? Conceptually I get that it falls to the body element, but when I do it this way, it seems the containing block doesn't have any physical dimensions, so everything gets placed as if the flow was normal.

For example, if div.container doesn't have a positioned ancestor, does #div still get placed?

Comment: Not sure I full understand your question. The physical dimension does not have to be defined by div.container, but it does not means it does not have a physical dimension, the dimension could come from the `<body>` or even `<html>`, if you look at the native `<body>` with different browsers, you will see each have slightly different dimensions with different margin sets. If `div.container` does not have a position explicitly, it will assumed the ancestor have a default position of `position=static` which means elements render in order, as they appear in the document flow.

Answer (score 3):

Setting `position:relative` on the `body` element makes absolute positioning relative to the entire body element (including off-screen parts), rather than just the initially visible part of the page. See the definition of the [initial containing block](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details) in the CSS specification. For instance, `position:absolute;bottom:0` will usually position an element at the bottom of the initially visible part of the page, whereas with `position:relative` on the `body`, it will position the element at the very bottom of the page (if its nearest positioned ancestor is the `body` element).

Answer (score -1):

The parent of all elements that you enter in, is body, so body considered relative  of position. because , you can move any element inside body it means the body has position and its position is relative by default without type it in. so I don't know what are you need. but I tried to explain it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).